# Jquery changing state of (this).parent on radio select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

Apologies if this has been asked before.

I have a script which adds/removes a class from a parent when the checkbox is selected. Works fine.

However, when I change the checkbox to a radio (in the script and the HTML), the script only ADDS the class to the parent - it doesn't remove it when another radio is selected.

Sorry, I'm VERY new to JS, and can't figure this out.

```
Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/RussellJones/Lh1ymzax/1/
```

And the custom class for the checkbox is based on this codepen, which is why the HTML is formatted this way.
    http://codepen.io/lavoiesl/pen/rjcIx

Thank you for any help you can give!

Comment: Always post your code in your question please.

Comment: Sorry! I'm, new to this, apologies if I'm going about it incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `.siblings()` to find the siblings and remove their class. Two more things:

1) instead of using `.parent().parent().parent().` you can simply use `.closest()` and pass the class you are targeting. This will traverse upwards through the DOM and find the `class` you're looking for. It will also still work if you add another parent to your HTML

2) You don't need an `else` statement now because you'll be removing the class from the other `.selectable-row` on click

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input:radio').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest(".selectable-row").addClass("selected-row").siblings(".selectable-row").removeClass("selected-row");
    } 
   });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lh1ymzax/4/)

And as Jack pointed out, you have a float issue that can be corrected by setting `overflow` to either `auto` or `hidden` on `.selectable-row` in your CSS. Updated my fiddle to reflect.

Comment: You may also want to add something like `overflow: auto;` to the `.selectable-row`. It looks like there is a `float` issue in the example.

Comment: Yep good call. Wasn't even paying attention that haha I updated my post

Comment: Thank you all VERY much. You're a great little community :)